# How do you convert the input from a JTextfield from a string to a char?

Tags: java

For Hangman, we have a method checkLetter, which checks to see if the letter the user inputted is in the array char[] that has the word the user is trying to guess for Hangman. Here is the code we have so far:

```
 public void playGame(String filename)
  {
//a randomword is read from a textfile, and converted from a string to an array of chars that has a char stored in each index

  randomWord = array[(int)(Math.random() * array.length)];
  int length = randomWord.length();

  char[] arr = randomWord.toCharArray();
 }
```

Then, we have the method checkLetter.

```
 public boolean checkLetter()
     {
  char inputLetter = letter.charAt(letter.getText()); //letter is the name of the JTextField where the user inputs the letter they are guessing
     }
```

We are kind of confused as to what to do next, and we would appreciate any help on how to proceed from here. Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you have tried and what fails? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: We are asking how to convert an input from a JTextField to a char, instead of a string.

Comment: Why do you store the word in `char[]`?

Comment: I don't understand the question, you already do it with the randomWord...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length of the `String` is (at least) one, you can do this:

```
String text = letter.getText(); // get the value of the JTextField
char ch = text.charAt(0);       // get the first letter as char
```

or in one statement, either

```
char ch = letter.getText().charAt(0);
```

or

```
char ch = letter.getText().toCharArray()[0];
```